# Retrofit 2.0, Jackson and polymorphism: Could not find creator property with name <...>

Tags: java, android, json, jackson, retrofit

I'm currently consuming a REST API with RetroFit & Jackson. Consider the following response JSON when retrieving users based on a search query when:

One result was found

```
{
    name: "API name",
    results: {
        count: 1
        users: {
            username: "username",
            age: 15
        }
    }
}
```

Multiple results were found

```
{
    name: "API name",
    results: {
        count: 2,
        users: [{
            username: "username1",
            age: 18
        }, {
            username: "username2",
            age: 19
        }]
    }
}
```

As you can see, the users-property contains dynamic JSON: based on the found results, the value of "users" could either be a list of user objects, or 1 user object.

As such, I've designed my Java POJOs using polymorphism, as follows:

```
public class UserResponse {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String apiName

    @JsonProperty("results")
    private AResultList resultList

    //Getters & Setters

    //Constructor
    @JsonCreator
    public UserResponse(@JsonProperty("name") String name, @JsonProperty("results") AResultList r) {
        this.apiName = name;
        this.resultList = r;
    }
}

@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
        property = "classType"
        )
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ResultObject.class, name="ResultObject"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ResultList.class, name="ResultList")
})
public abstract class AResultList {
    @JsonProperty("count)
    private long totalCount;

    //Getters & Setters

    //Constructors
    @JsonCreator
    public AResultList(@JsonProperty("count) long count) {
        this.totalCount = count;
    }
}

public class ResultObject extends AResultList {
    @JsonProperty("users")
    private User user;

    //Getters & Setters

    //Constructor
    @JsonCreator
    public ResultObject(@JsonProperty("count) long count, @JsonProperty("users") User u) {
        super(count);

        this.user = u;
    }
}

public class ResultList extends AResultList {
    @JsonProperty("users")
    private List<User> users;

    //Getters & Setters

    //Constructor
    @JsonCreator
    public ResultObject(@JsonProperty("count) long count, @JsonProperty("users") List<User> u) {
        super(count);

        this.users = u;
    }
}

public class User {
    @JsonProperty("username")
    private String username;

    @JsonProperty("age")
    private long userAge;

    //Getters & Setters

    //Constructor
    @JsonCreator
    public User(@JsonProperty("username") String u, @JsonProperty("age") long a) {
        this.userAge = a;
        this.username = u;
    }
}
```

For your information: A snippet for instantiating RetroFit

```
ObjectMapper o = new ObjectMapper();

retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create(o))
                .client(okClient)
                .build();
```

Trying to retrieve this information, however, results in the following error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Could not find creator property with name 'count' (in class org.namespace.AResultList)
at [Source: java.io.InputStreamReader@41cd2648; line: 1, column: 1]
```

I've been stuck on this "dynamic data" problem for 2 days now. Already tried to use GSON library and a lot of other things but to no avail. So I'd like to ask:
- Why is Jackson causing this? Is this a bug? Some users have already asked this question but the provided solutions did not work for my case.
 - Is this the correct way of handling data of which part is dynamic?

I've tested my code without the use of polymorphic classes (and only retrieving 1 User from the API) and object maps perfectly. The problem is caused by the polymorphism, but I cannot figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polymorphism configuration you're specifying in the Jackson annotations there is suggesting a `{"classType":"ResultObject",...}` or `{"classType":"ResultList",...}` is going to be in the JSON-- which it isn't. I'm not sure of the exact cause of the error you're receiving, but it seems to be looking for the creator on the abstract class since there is not type property.

[For polymorphism, Jackson needs something to read from the JSON to determine what type of bean to deserialize at this point: you don't really have one, just the array/objectness of `users`. I think therefore that Jackson's polymorphism support isn't a good fit for this situation]

In fact, to allow a property to either take a single item or a list of items, you just need to enable the `ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY` deserialization feature. However, this needs to be enabled globally, there doesn't seem to be a way to target it to a specific property.

```
public static final class UserResponse {
    public String name;
    public Results results;

    public static final class Results {
        public int count;
        public List<User> users;
    }

    public static final class User {
        public String username;
        public int age;
    }
}

@Test
public void reads_single_result() throws Exception {
    ObjectReader reader = new ObjectMapper().reader(UserResponse.class)
            .with(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
            .with(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES).with(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES);
    UserResponse response = reader.readValue("{ name: 'API name', results: { count: 1,"
            + " users: { username: 'username', age: 15 } } }");
    assertThat(response.results.users, iterableWithSize(1));
    assertThat(response.results.users.get(0).username, equalTo("username"));
}

@Test
public void reads_two_results() throws Exception {
    ObjectReader reader = new ObjectMapper().reader(UserResponse.class)
            .with(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
            .with(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES).with(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES);
    UserResponse response = reader.readValue("{ name: 'API name', results: { count: 2,"
            + " users: [{ username: 'username1', age: 18 }, { username: 'username2', age: 19 }] } }");
    assertThat(response.results.users, iterableWithSize(2));
    assertThat(response.results.users.get(0).username, equalTo("username1"));
    assertThat(response.results.users.get(1).username, equalTo("username2"));
}
```

Oh, and if you want to get rid of the useless results object in there, you can do that with a converter:

```
public static final class UserResponseWithConverter {
    public String name;
    @JsonProperty("results")
    @JsonDeserialize(converter = ConvertResultsToUserList.class)
    public List<User> users;

    public static final class Results {
        public int count;
        public List<User> users;
    }

    public static final class User {
        public String username;
        public int age;
    }

    public static final class ConvertResultsToUserList extends StdConverter<Results, List<User>> {
        @Override
        public List<User> convert(Results value) {
            return value.users;
        }
    }
}
```

Configuring for correct serialization is left as an exercise for the reader ;)

Comment: Thank you so much! The "ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY" Serialize option was all I needed. Your second answer of "converting" and stripping away the useless Results-property even comes in handy for some other data I have to convert.